# How to connect one PC and two laptops?

Tags: windows, networking, wireless-networking

I have two laptops (both having wireless capability), and a PC. I want to have them in one network (for playing a LAN game).  I have a router with a USB port and a LAN port.

Can this be done?

I tried this way but did not succeed: I connected the PC to the router, one laptop to the router and the other one via a hosted network to the first laptop. But, as I mentioned, it was not a successful network.

If this configuration cannot be done, is there another way, perhaps without using the modem/router (for example, directly connecting the PC to one laptop and connecting the two laptops by Wi-Fi)?

Comment: Normally that kind of router cannot use both USB and the ethernet port at the same time. What make and model is it? You could buy a switch or replace your router with one that has 4 ethernet ports.

Comment: @DavidPostill it is PLANET (ADE-3410). the PC and the laptop which are connected to the router are able to ping each other, honestly the problem is the second laptop, which I don't know how to connect it to those two!

Comment: Then buy a switch or replace your router with one that has 4 ethernet ports.

Comment: As a bonus with new router you will get wireless as well ;)

Comment: @DavidPostill thanks! but I wondered is there anyway besides buying a new router!!

Comment: http://lifehacker.com/5369381/turn-your-windows-7-pc-into-a-wireless-hotspot

Comment: If you choose not to get an Ethernet switch or a wireless access point (or wireless router), then either the PC or laptop that you use as the bridge will have to be powered-up and booted so that the second laptop can have network access.  Eventually you will discover that this setup is inconvenient.  The optimal and simple solution is to add an Ethernet switch to your ADSL modem+router, and connect each PC/laptop to the switch with Cat5/5e cable.  FWIW I have a similar ADSL modem+router from my ISP.

Comment: [ADE-3410 User Manual](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=11&cad=rja&uact=8&ved=0CE0QFjAK&url=http%3A%2F%2Fpdfstream.manualsonline.com%2F0%2F08efdc5f-08cb-4dc5-87b7-5f15d819229b.pdf&ei=3TuUVYDkJ4TtsAXxiYCQBw&usg=AFQjCNEqHq9n5tkD8DsujsBGVwzFjncyow&bvm=bv.96952980,d.b2w) for your ADSL modem+router

Answer (score 0):

Most routers are wireless, and also include 4/5 physical Ethernet ports on them.

If it is wireless and does include a few physical Ethernet ports, then just connect the PC a physical Ethernet port on the back of the router and the two laptops wirelessly to the router.

If your router isn't wireless or doesn't contain multiple Ethernet ports, write back with what if does have.

Also, keep in mind that you mostly likely can't use both USB and Ethernet at the same time.

Comment: as I mentioned in the question, the router is not wireless and it only has a USB port, and a ethernet port. both USB and ethernet are used to connect to internet at the same time and again as I mentioned before these two are able to ping each other.

Comment: This does not really answer the question.  You just describe how routers have wireless capabilities.

Comment: It's slow but it can be done. Creat an adhoc wireless connecting and bridge your wireless laptop with the other one. Basically it would work like this. PC plugged in, laptop 1 plugged in. Laptop one also makes a second adhoc wireless connection to laptop2. Laptop shared the Internet connection it has from its physical port out through the adhoc wireless connection. Laptop2 connects to laptop1 and receives internet via that shared connection.

Comment: It's a little outdated but the process should still be the same if you are using windows 7 or 8.       http://mobile.wi-fiplanet.com/tutorials/article.php/3822651/How-to-Create-an-Ad-Hoc-Network-Part-2.htm

Answer (score 0):

One simple way to do this would be to purchase a switch.

It simply plugs into you routers Ethernet port and has multiple ports on itself, allowing multiple Ethernet devices connect to the one port on your router

A switch will enable you to plug both your laptops and you computer into it by Ethernet and you can plug the switch into the router to give all the connected computers internet access.

Using a network switch will enable you to quickly send and receive files and play LAN games  with almost zero latency (normally between 1 - 10 ping)

Switches can come in many sizes for connecting multiple computers in a network, I myself have a 5 port TpLink switch I purchased off Amazon for £15 which has been working perfectly for almost 4 months.